# JDBC Connection Pooling Clarification

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have set up jdbc connection pooling in a java-ee environment by doing the following changes.

```
    The context.xml 

<Context> 
        <Resource name="jdbc/mysybase" auth="Container" 
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver" 
                  url="jdbc:sybase:Tds:H2S33.studtrack.com:2025/student" 
                  username="scott" password="tiger" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" 
                  maxWait="-1"/> 
    </Context> 


    In The web.xml file 
    <resource-ref> 
     <description>Sybase Datasource example</description> 
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/mysybase</res-ref-name> 
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
    </resource-ref> 


    And the jsp page 

    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%> 
    <%@page import="javax.naming.Context"%> 
    <%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%> 
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%> 
    <%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%> 
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%> 
    <%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource"%> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Obtaining a Connection</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <% 
        Connection conn = null; 
        ResultSet result = null; 
        Statement stmt = null; 
         try { 
           Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env"); 
           DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mysybase"); 
           conn = ds.getConnection(); 
        if (conn != null)  
        { 
            String message = "Got Connection " + conn.toString() + ", "; 
            out.write(message); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            out.write("hello no conn obtained"); 

        } 

            stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
            result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Student"); 
        while(result.next()) 
        { 
            out.write(result.getString("name")); 
        } 

         } 
         catch (SQLException e) { 
             out.write("Error occurred " + e); 
          } 

    %> 

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Now i want the jdbc pooling to be available in normal java classes as well.
Do i need to make any changes if i want the pooling to be available in java classes.
Can i get a connection object in a java class just as i got the connection in the jsp as shown above.

```
Connection conn = null; 
ResultSet result = null; 
Statement stmt = null;
Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env"); 
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mysybase"); 
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) You can set a contextListener to initialize connection only once and get logical conn from the pool (gues you use tomcat's DBCP).

2.) Yes, once you start a connection (driver sets a socket and the pool gets initialized) from context data, you can get a connection (from the pool) properly invoking that from any java class.

3.) Try not to put pure Java code in JSPs. Just a rule of the road: is treated as a poor decision.

Comment: So even though i set up jdbc pooling for jsp/servlets do you mean i can use this pooling in pure java classes as well as i did in jsp/servlets.

Comment: As you are setting the datasource in context, you can use it when the context initializes (and, for example, add it to the session). Here is explained the contextListener idea, where you can add to session the conn instance http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/ServletContextListener-example.shtml

Comment: I wanted to use jdbc connection pooling in pure java classes not in servlets.

Comment: The example is just an example. The fact is: you can always explore the context of your application and retrieve info. The thing is: if you don't persist connection info (as in session), you'll be doing a lot of work every single time, creating a whole pool for a query.

Comment: Now do i need to add the conn instance to the session and then try to access the pool in pure java classes?

Comment: If you're in a web container like tomcat, then you're surely using servlets. Even using a framework like cocoon or spring, servlets are there handling sessions to persist user's data. Anyway, people can suggest many ways to set your conn to be available on POJO, but in the end we all need to know how are you using those "pure java classes" so we can help you out

Comment: The connection pooling was basically for web-site related work.But now i want the pooling to be available to java classes used to do back-end reporting which is in no way related to web-site.

Comment: But the backend activities will run over the same context, right? Even if you separate frontend from backend functions, resourced could be shared and the architecture won't change in a radical way.

Comment: I tried to execute a java program with the same setting which i had for jsp/servlets i got the following error: Error occurred javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: I modified my server.xml as per the instructions in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html changing the appropriate values to sybase db but i still get the error mentioned in the previous post

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you used JNDI(Java Naming and Directory Interface) standard for preparing connection, so you can same code in java classes for access to connection.(of course you have to initial Context instance befor using it for example have to set connection factory for it ).

I see your code and find these note, for better application you have to observance it:

1. You using jdbc in presentation layer, better approch is:"desing Data Access layer".
2. You can using a famous connection pooling, such as "C3P0" and "Apache Tomcat 7 Connection Pool", these connection pools have more option for enterprise application.(of course you have to test your current connection pool with these suggestion)
3. You can use a ORM for data access layer, this is object oriented design.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to set connection factory" for accessing the jdbc pool in pure java classes.Do you mean i have to add factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" 
attribute in the context.xml

Comment: No, my means you have to set JNDI(stand alone or web application) before using it, for example set these in stand alone application manually: javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY or javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URLor etc options. You set these options into application server config file in web application environment. For better helping, you have to explain completly.

Comment: I tried to execute a java program with the same setting which i had for jsp/servlets i got the following error: Error occurred javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: By server config file do you mean server.xml.What do i set in this file and i have an error without setting any JNDI as shown in the previous comment.How do i rectify the same.

Comment: I modified my server.xml as per the instructions in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html changing the appropriate values to sybase db but i still get the error mentioned in the previous post.